# Realtek RTL8822BU driver from arm to arm64 to run on RPi 3B+ (Kali)

Tags: arm, driver, wifi, raspberry-pi3, arm64

I recently purchased a new wireless adapter for use with Kali Linux running on a Raspberry Pi 3B+.

The driver described within the specification was RTL8812. I assumed (you know what they say) that it would be RTL8812AU for which there is an ARM64 driver available to be installed on Kali.

However, much to my surprise after looking up the id Product once I plugged it in, it is actually RTL8812BU (https://wikidevi.com/wiki/Realtek_RTL8812BU_USB_Module).

```
[    2.082339] systemd[1]: Detected architecture arm64.
[    2.099491] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <kali>.
[    2.159353] usb 1-1.1.2: new high-speed USB device number 4 using dwc_otg
[    2.249231] usb 1-1.1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=b812, bcdDevice= 2.10
[    2.251726] usb 1-1.1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    2.254302] usb 1-1.1.2: Product: USB3.0 802.11ac 1200M Adapter
[    2.254309] usb 1-1.1.2: Manufacturer: Realtek
[    2.254318] usb 1-1.1.2: SerialNumber: 123456

Machine: Linux kali 4.19.29-Re4son-v8+ #6 SMP PREEMPT Wed Mar 27 00:15:50 UTC 2019 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

From my research. There is a driver that supports RTL8812BU which is RTL8822BU (https://github.com/EntropicEffect/rtl8822bu)

This driver supports arm, but not arm64 which is what I require.

There is also a driver for RTL8812AU that supports ARM64 for RPi (https://github.com/diederikdehaas/rtl8812AU).

I have tried to combine both drivers in a number of ways, but I imagine the underlying .c files used within the drivers may need to be changed in some way. There are a lot of files and I have plenty of curiosity and not enough experience.

Can someone with wireless driver experience please try and point me in the right direction?

Would it make the most sense to take the necessary pieces for RTL8822BU and build them into the RTL8812AU driver that already supports ARM64 for RPi?

Or should I attempt to port the RTL8822BU driver to support ARM64?

I am hopefully using the correct terminology.

I have very basic coding abilities, so even just telling me not to waste my time would be much appreciated! Thank you in advance for your time and consideration.